# How to separate inconsistent columns in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

Here I'm attaching a dummy data, where, the columns are inconsistent,means,sometimes some fields are not present, how to separate & fill columns if it is 'none', just assume that all those columns are features

dummy dataframe :

```
feature1 : abc

feature2 : bfj

feature4 : 

feature5 : re


feature1 : werq

feature3 : kgh

feature4 : hjyj

feature5 : re


feature1 : hg

feature2 : jhgyj

feature3 : ytyitli

feature4 : guyhk

feature5 : yyjhj


feature2 : tyty

feature3 : ytrtf

feature4 : ewhgf

feature5 : ihyty
```

this is what I'm expecting,

```
 feature1     feature2       feature3         feature4       feature5 

  abc           bfj           None              None            re

  werq          None          kgh               hjyj            re

  hg            jhgyj         ytyitli           guyhk          yyjhj

  None          tyty          ytrtf             ewhgf          ihyty
```

Thanks

Comment: There is always last feature, `feature5` in each group?

Comment: Can you tell about how the data is available? Like is it a csv file from which you want to create a dataframe ? How is each record identified etc

Comment: @jezrael: actually its a big data, so, sometimes 'feature5' is absent, columns are inconsistent

Comment: @mujjiga: this is a dummy data, I have 20+ feature columns, actual data looks like this ,& it is a comma delimited 'csv' file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create dictionary with unique values in ordering like need in final columns, here by sorting with `enumerate` with sorted unique values, then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column, get  difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `<` and create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and final `Dataframe` by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.strip(' :')

d = {v: k for k, v in  dict(enumerate(df['col1'].sort_values().unique())).items()}
print (d)
{'feature1': 0, 'feature2': 1, 'feature3': 2, 'feature4': 3, 'feature5': 4}

df['g'] = df['col1'].map(d).diff().lt(-1).cumsum()

df1 = df.pivot('g', 'col1', 'col2')
print (df1)
col1 feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4 feature5
g                                                
0         abc      bfj      NaN     None       re
1        werq      NaN      kgh     hjyj       re
2          hg    jhgyj  ytyitli    guyhk    yyjhj
3         NaN     tyty    ytrtf    ewhgf    ihyty
```